# QGIS WMS GetFeatureInfo

Tags: qgis, wms

I want to extract a feature info from a WMS automatically (behind the WMS there is a GML Database). Is there a way to that easily in QGIS? As a coordinate that requests the feature info I want to use the centroid of a shape. With the cursor I can select and copy the information...

I read that queries like that are not possible since the WMS is exactly made for keeping users from getting all the information?

Comment: QGIS supports GetFeatureInfo requests using the information tool.  The feature information returned will depend on what the service provider has configured for the service.

Comment: A GetFeatureInfo request is a request for a pixel coordinate an image (the GetMap request)